# Entity Framework Core: Table names are being mapped to include the namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I recently updated a ASP.NET 5 project to used ASP.NET Core (RC2) and Entity Framework Core. Everything has been okay so far besides little nuances here and there, but I've after trying to change the name of one of my tables, I noticed that my migration was trying to reference an incorrect table (i.e "MyProject.Models.Blog" instead of just "Blog").

I've been going through some of the documentation and I've tried a few things, such as using data annotations. My models are set up similar to how they are in there documentation (using different naming/data specific to my project, but same idea):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Blog>();
        builder.Entity<Post>();
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

So when I make a change, go to create a new migration, and look at the generated migration file, I can see the the migrationBuilder is now trying to make changes to a "MyProject.Models.Post" table, instead of the "Post" table, which it used to do. I have done a few migrations before updating to Core and haven't changed anything with my models since the update, so this is new behavior.

Edit: I should note that I am currently using the "[Table("Post")]" Data annotations on my models, but it's not helping the problem either.

Edit 2: Here's a link to my migration file contents (with the names changed out) - http://pastebin.com/CZmXTBEM

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to remove old migrations (you probably don't if you have an existing database), here's what needs to be done:

1. Take your pre-EF-core code snapshot
2. In your model class, make a simple dummy change, such as adding a simple property
3. Add a dummy migration `dotnet ef migrations add dummy`. This will create a migration and regenerate the snapshot.
4. In the snapshot, remove the code that defines your newly created column.
5. Delete the migration .cs file, and revert dummy changes to your model.

That's it: newly added migrations will use the correct table names.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some issue with migrations.

In my case it's work as you (and me) expect - name of table is taken from name of DbSet variable (not Type like in RC1), for example:

- for `public DbSet<Blog> Blog { get; set; }` EF Core create `Blog` table in my Db,
- and for `public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }` EF Core create `Posts` table in my Db.

However in me case - I have created new/clean project after installing RC2, and I move my code to this new project... and after that I have created new migrations... So I have new/clean migrations created on RC2.

I assume that you have few migrations created on RC1 and you create new one after migrating project to RC2 - maybe here is problem ?

**Can you show me code of your migrations files ?**

- but, please include file, do not paste all code here ;)
- or you can just give link to repository with your code.

Also you can try something like that (it's solution for other problem, but probably can help in your case also - it's not tested by me):

```
foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    entity.Relational().TableName = entity.DisplayName();
}
```

Still - in my opinion - it's not expected situation.

You can read more about migrating form RC1 to RC2 and about changing in table naming below, but I have not found any mention about that kind of behaviour:

- [EF Core Upgrading from RC1 to RC2](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc1-rc2-upgrade.html#table-naming-convention-changes)
- [EF Core Table Mapping](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relational/tables.html)
- [EF Core: Table names now taken from DbSet names (starting in RC2)](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/167)
- [Discussion for Table names now taken from DbSet names (starting in RC2)](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4996)

Comment: Thank for the reply. I didn't know how to attach a file so here's a link to the content - http://pastebin.com/CZmXTBEM. I replaced the some of the names to "Blog" and "Post".

Comment: Thanks, but why `I replaced the some of the names to "Blog" and "Post".` ?? I would like see ALL migrations files (not modified in any way)...

Comment: It's not enough information to figure out this, however... You can try delete all migrations (make backup first) and next create new (clean) migrations on RC2.

Comment: Removing the old migrations (and snapshot) fixed the problem. Apparently there were a few changes in how migrations are generated that causes issues if there are old ones still there.

Answer (score 0):

Removing old migrations and the old snapshot fixed the problem.

Comment: That's great. I suggest mark this answer as solved/solution - this will help other people in the future ;)